# Angular 4 And Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular4-httpclient

In angular 4 at a client side, i have a post method when i click on it ->

```
 var json=JSON.stringify({id:"1",name:"par",title:"ssss"});
 var params='json'+json;
 this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/users/insertData",params, optio
 .subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()));}
```

after click on this at server side, I am using  node express js,
so the problem at server side I am getting data that type which is not acceptable for the database my SQL so data is getting ->

```
     { 'json{"id":"1","name":"par","title":"ssss"}' : ' ' }
```

but I want to get data is ->only JSON form

```
      {"id":"1","name":"par","title":"ssss"}
```

so please give me some solution ...

Comment: Why you concatenate the string json in this line??var params='json'+json;

Comment: var json=JSON.stringify({id:"1",name:"par",title:"ssss"});
 this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/users/insertData",json)
 .subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()));}

Comment: instead of previous ok

Comment: Have you add header application json??
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

Comment: Content type should mention as json

Comment: I have already added header part.

Comment: but I am getting data at server side -{ 'json{"id":"1","name":"par","title":"ssss"}' : ' ' }

Comment: Try without stringify var var params={id:"1",name:"par",title:"ssss"};

Comment: same error like this

Answer (score 1):

Try without stringify

```
var params={id:"1",name:"par",title:"ssss"}
```

Comment: i did but no effect

Comment: you have any solution of server side

Comment: Sorry, nope but I suspect client side

Answer (score 0):

This line: `var params='json'+json;`

You are concatenating a string with some data in JSON form.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with that, but that is why the data is not  JSON when you receive it on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

By default Angular converts all your form submission data into json, even if you submit a model it is converted to json before sending it to the server. Unless you explicitly want to submit form data.

Secondly as pointed out by Adam, what are you trying to achieve using this piece of code `var params='json'+json;`